# Javascript, button load images by folder ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gallery, image-gallery

thank you all for the answers, your infos are very usefull for the future and to learn how to build. But my problem is a but harder to solve when we are very newbie coding.

i have this function on my (purchased) script. that script doesnt came with image gallery, so the part to multi upload images to Shop id image folders is ok, i made that. But the script with ship info (small popup) is all on javascript i've added so i will show the original script and the one with my newbie dumb changes. Maybe your expertise can help me solve this madness xD Thank you all again!

Original (just the part that shows the shop info and where i want to add the button of image gallery):

```
function info_window_content(v) {

    var info_window_string = "<div class='maps_popup'>";

    if(v.img != '') {
        info_window_string += "<img class='img' src='"+v.img+"' alt='"+v.name+"' /></a>";
    }

     var splitaddress = "";
     saddress = v.address.split(" ");
     for(i=0;i<saddress.length;i++){
        splitaddress += saddress[i]+" ";
         if(i==4){
          splitaddress += "<br>";
         }
     }

    info_window_string += "<h1>"+v.name+"</h1><p>"+splitaddress+"</p>";

    if(v.telephone != '') {
        info_window_string += "<p class='tel'>"+v.titletel+": "+v.telephone+"</p>";
    }
    if(v.email != '') {
        info_window_string += "<p class='email'>"+v.titleemail+": <a href='mailto:"+v.email+"'>"+v.email+"</a></p>";
    }

    if(v.website != '') {

        if(v.website.substring(0, 4)!="http"){
        info_window_string += "<p class='web'>"+v.titlewebsite+": <a href='http://"+v.website+"' target='new'>http://"+v.website+"</a></p>";
        } else {
            info_window_string += "<p class='web'>"+v.titlewebsite+": <a href='"+v.website+"' target='new'>"+v.website+"</a></p>";
        }
    }

    if(v.description != '') {
        info_window_string += "<p class='description'>"+v.description+"</p>";
    }


    if(v.cat_img != '') {
        info_window_string += "<div class='products'><img src='"+v.cat_img+"' style='max-width:15px; max-height:15px;' /> "+v.cat_name+"</div>";
    }

    if(v.email != ''){
      info_window_string += "<span class='email'><center><a href='mailto:"+v.email+"' class='contact-clinic button blue-button' style='display:block;"+
                      "padding:5px 10px;"+
                      "margin-top:10px;"+ 
                      "margin-bottom:10px;"+
                      "margin-left:3px;"+
                      "border:1px solid #8b8b8b;"+
                      "text-align: center;"+
                      "font-weight:bold;"+
                      "width:190px;'>"+v.titlecontactstore+"</a></center></span>";


    }

    info_window_string += "<a href='javascript:streetView("+v.lat+","+v.lng+");'>Street view</a> | <a href='javascript:zoomHere("+v.lat+","+v.lng+");'>Zoom here</a> | <a href='javascript:direction(\""+v.address+"\","+v.lat+","+v.lng+");'>Directions</a>";
    info_window_string += "</div>";

return info_window_string;
}

function gallery(){
                api_gallery=['images/fullscreen/1.JPG','images/fullscreen/2.jpg','images/fullscreen/3.JPG'];
                api_titles=['API Call Image 1','API Call Image 2','API Call Image 3'];
                api_descriptions=['Description 1','Description 2','Description 3'];
}
function streetView(lat,lng){

           // street view
           street = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { 

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            zoomControl: false,
            enableCloseButton: true,
            addressControl: false,
            panControl: true,
            linksControl: true
          });

}

function zoomHere(lat,lng){

    map.setZoom(15);
    var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setCenter(currentLatLng);

}


function direction(dest,lat,lng){

     $('#direction').show();
     $('#results').hide();
     $('#dest-direction').val(dest);


    $('#direction-form').submit(function() {

     var ori = $('#origin-direction').val();

        map.setZoom(7);
        var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        map.setCenter(currentLatLng);

            var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsRenderer.setMap(map);    
            directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById('direction'));

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var request = {
              origin: ori, 
              destination: dest,
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
              unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
              } else {
                //alert('Error: ' + status);
                $('#direction').append('<table width="100%"><tr><td>Direction not found. Please try again.</td></tr></table>');
              } 
            });

      $('#direction-form').nextAll().remove();
      return false;

    });

}

function directionBack(){

     $('#direction').hide();
     $('#results').show();
     resetDirection();
}

function resetDirection(){
    gmap_location_lookup($('#address').val(),'200','');
     $('#direction').html('');
     $('#direction').html('<form method="post" id="direction-form"><p><table><tr><td>Origin:</td><td><input id="origin-direction" name="origin-direction" class="orides-txt" type=text /></td></tr><tr><td>Destination:</td><td><input id="dest-direction" name="dest-direction" class="orides-txt" type=text readonly /></td></tr></table><div id="get-dir-button" class="get-dir-button"><input type=submit id="get-direction" class="btn" value="Get Direction"> <a href="javascript:directionBack()">Back</a></div></p></form>');
    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#origin-direction")[0], {});
}
```

Before the function info_window_content(v) i've added this code:

```
             function Show(ident) {
            var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery"); // The DIV element

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // AJAX magic
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    // Put the images in the DIV
                    gallery.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            // Call the PHP file to load the images
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "image.gallery.php?id=" + ident, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

and then i've added an button like this:

```
info_window_string += "<center><button onclick='Show(1)' id='Btn1' type='button' class='contact-clinic button blue-button'> Image Gallery</button><br><br></center>";
```

and i've also create the `"image.gallery.php"` that is on main folder

sorry for the big testment and thank you very much again.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i tried to make that button like that to get the images from the folder by the id

Comment: info_window_string += "<center><a href='<?php echo ROOT.('imgs/stores/'.$store['id'].'/'$v.); ?>' class='contact-clinic button blue-button'> Image Gallery</a><br><br></center>";

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the question is still unclear, but I'll make some assumptions:

1. You want a button that when clicked is going to open a new page.
2. The new page is going to display all the images in that folder
3. You do not want a server directory list, but an actual HTML page that displays the images.
4. A querystring parameter would be an acceptable solution (as opposed to a url rewrite processor).
5. Security is not an issue for you.
6. Lastly, that the directories with images are going to be subdirectories of the current page the user is viewing.

If this is the case, you'll need a PHP script to process a request for which folder to list the images. Let's call that page, imageList.php.

```
# imageList.php (do not include this line in the file)
<html><head><title>Image List</title></head><body>
<?php
$directoryName = $_GET['dir'];
foreach(scandir($directoryName) as $f) {
    $ext = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($ext == 'png' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'gif') {
        echo '<img src="' . $directoryName . '/' . $f . '" alt="" />';
    }
} ?>
</body></html>
```

Then your link is going to be something like this:

```
<a href="imageList.php?dir=dirName" target="_blank">Click this to see the images</a>
```

The reason I mention security is because this opens your application up to someone putting in any directory they want.

If you want something more secure, you should consider using an ID system that is handled server side to invisibly pull the directory images from.

An http_rewrite processor would be a bit prettier as well, but that's a much broader subject than just this question.

Hope that helps, please feel free to comment if you need me to narrow something down.

Answer (score 0):

To do an Image Galley you will need:

1. Image files with standard name
2. AJAX
3. DIV element
4. PHP to load the images

The HTML will have a function in Javascript (AJAX) to call the PHP file, take the result of the PHP file, and put it in the DIV element.

It is not dificult:

---

First the HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
    <center>

        <script>
            function Show(ident) {
                var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery"); // The DIV element

                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // AJAX magic
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        // Put the images in the DIV
                        gallery.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                // Call the PHP file to load the images
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "image.gallery.php?id=" + ident, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>

        <button onclick="Show(1)" id="Btn1" type="button"> Gallery 1 </button>
        <button onclick="Show(2)" id="Btn2" type="button"> Gallery 2 </button>
        <hr>
        <div id="gallery"> </div>

    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Second the PHP:

name it as `"image.gallery.php"`, the script below work with images named as: `1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...` saved in a folder named: `store-1, store-2, ...`

```
<?php

    // get the ID from the xmlhttp.open call
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    // You will need a way to know the amount of images in each folder
    if ($id == 1) { $quant = 5; }
    if ($id == 2) { $quant = 4; }

    // show the images
    for($cont=0; $cont<$quant; $cont++)
    {
        echo " <img src=\"store-".$id ."/".$cont.".jpg\" border=1 /> ";
    }

?>
```